# JTree - how can i stop children from showing relative path?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

Before we start, I'd like to note that I'm rather new to JTree and its relatives.

The children in my nodes show the relative path back to its parent, but I'd like for it not to.

Here is a picture of what it looks like

http://puu.sh/azCJa/8dd84029b7.png
[image: JTree]

I'd like for it to be like:

```
testing 0
>testing 1
>>file 1
```

**not**

```
testing 0
>testing 0\testing 1
>>...
```

Here is some runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class NGui {

    JFrame frame;
    private JTree tree;

    public NGui() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 493, 608);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 212, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        tree = new JTree(addNodes(null, new File(getWorkPath())));
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

        tree.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tree);

        tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(
                new TreeSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                        treeValueChanged(e);
                    }
                });
    }

    private String getWorkPath() {
        return System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Program Name\\";
    }

    private void treeValueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode addNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top, File dir) {
        String curPath = dir.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
                curPath.replace(getWorkPath(), ""));
        if (top != null) { // should only be null at root
            log("Adding curPath: " + root);
            top.add(root);
        }
        Vector<String> ol = new Vector<String>();
        String[] tmp = dir.list();
        for (String s : tmp) {
            log("Adding file: " + s);
            ol.addElement(s);
        }
        Collections.sort(ol, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        File file;
        Vector<String> files = new Vector<String>();
        // for dirs
        for (int i = 0; i < ol.size(); i++) {
            String filePath = ol.elementAt(i);
            String newPath;

            if (curPath.equals(".")) // if root
                newPath = filePath;
            else
                // not root
                newPath = curPath + File.separator + filePath;
            file = new File(newPath);
            log(String.format("cur: %s | file: %s | new: %s", curPath,
                    filePath, newPath));
            // if not a file then go inside folder and get files
            if (file.isDirectory())
                addNodes(root, file);
            else if (filePath.contains(".txt")) // txt files only
                files.addElement(filePath);

        }
        // for files
        for (int fnum = 0; fnum < files.size(); fnum++)
            root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(files.elementAt(fnum).replace(getWorkPath(), ""), true));
        return root;
    }

    public void log(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I would look at `newPath = curPath + File.separator + filePath` a little more closely, very closely.  Add a breakpoint at this point in your code and fire up you IDE's debugger and inspect the result of this value and see what you find...

Comment: I have looked and still don't quite see the problem. Changing anything there either causes a StackOverflow or stops listing of children in nodes. Adding a runnable example to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your issue is here...

```
if (curPath.equals(".")) // if root
    newPath = filePath;
else
    // not root
    newPath = curPath + File.separator + filePath;
```

Basically, what it's saying is, unless you are the root node, prefix `curPath` (which is `dir.getPath()`) to the `filePath`...which is why you get `path/path` in your tree...

The entire `if` statement is pointless, based on what you want to achieve and be complete replace with...

```
newPath = filePath;
```

In face, you could get rid of `newPath` and simple use `filePath` directly...

**Updated**

Your core design is simply not capable of doing what it seems you are trying to achieve...

Trying to maintain path information as `String`s is overly complicated and error prone, it is much simpler to maintain the `File` reference, which provides you with all the information you need to render the file name and access the file for other purposes...the right tool for the job...

Some background, the default `TreeCellRenderer` used by `JTree` simply uses the `toString` method of the object in the `TreeModel` to renderer something to the UI.  In the case of `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, this simply uses the `toString` method of the `userData` object you pass it, so this means, when you do `curPath.replace(getWorkPath(), "")`, this is what eventually gets to the screen, but isn't what you want.

Instead, you should be passing the actual `File` to the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and using a custom `TreeCellRenderer` to modify the value going to the screen, for example...

[image: File Tree]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class NGui {

    JFrame frame;
    private JTree tree;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                new NGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public NGui() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 212, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        tree = new JTree(addNodes(new File(getWorkPath())));
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

        tree.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tree);

        tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(
                new TreeSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                        treeValueChanged(e);
                    }
                });
        tree.setCellRenderer(new FileTreeCellRenderer());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private String getWorkPath() {
//        return System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Program Name\\";
        return ".";
    }

    private void treeValueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode addNodes(File dir) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(dir);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                node.add(addNodes(file));
            } else {
                node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    public class FileTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                value = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).getUserObject();
                if (value instanceof File) {
                    value = ((File) value).getName();
                }
            }
            return super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at [Customizing a Tree's Display](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display) for more details

Comment: curPath is the path to the folder

filePath is the file/folder itself


Your suggestion doesnt work, **unless** im doing it wrong.

Comment: But you don't need it for display purpose, the `DefaultTreeNode` only needs the `filePath` value...in fact, I would stop using `String` and use `File` instead, but that would require to provide a `TreeCellRenderer`

Comment: I need the absolute path to the file because I am previewing and modifying selected file, that's why I am doing it the way I am.

Comment: That seems a lot easier than i was making it. Thanks :)